# FFmpeg concatenating outputs with different times causes blank stream

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm working on a video editor and have a timeline. The inputs in the timeline need to go through the scale filter. Then the output of that needs to go through an overlay filter.

They get overlaid on a blank background set at 1080x1080. Then there is the possibility that there is a transition between two outputs.

So I have programmatically built this command. I found it easier to work with it like this. It logically makes sense to me. I am not sure why when I concatenate the outputs, in the end, I get a blank white stream.

It must have to do with the order of events here. Maybe the overlay and between filter is lost when it's concatenated?

```
ffmpeg
  -i "0.jpg"
  -i "1.jpg"
  -f lavfi
  -i color=c=white:s=1080x1080
  -filter_complex "

    // first scale all media inputs (2 in this case)
    [0:v]scale=1194:1490[out1],
    [1:v]scale=1176:1763[out2],

    // overlay the new outputs onto the blank canvas setting a time
    [2:v][out1]overlay=-56:-119:enable='between(t,0,5)'[out101],
    [2:v][out2]overlay=-47:-250:enable='between(t,5.01,10)'[out102],

    // if there was a transiton between the first input and second
    // ... [out101][out102]gltransition=duration=1[main] DONE

    // in this case there is no transition so we just concat
    [out101][out102]concat=n=2[main]

  "
  -map "[main]"
  -ac 2
  -vcodec libx264
  -preset veryfast
  -crf 27
  -pix_fmt yuv420p
  -vb 20M
  -t 00:00:10
  out.mp4
```

This pattern works well for me because I can easily pick which two outputs to transition between, create new output, then concatenate the rest. I think I am thinking about this correctly.

The problem seems to be the `enable='between()'` is lost when I re concatenate the stream.

So I am wondering in my logic where are things breaking down causing this problem?

Here is an example of the result of the command above https://storycreatoruploads2.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/e236ff60-55b8-11ea-aa4b-91efa707fae7

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) What `-f lavfi -i color=c=white:s=1080x1080` does is generate a white video stream of indefinite length, so it never terminates.

2) What `[2:v][out1]overlay=-56:-119:enable='between(t,0,5)'[out101]` does is overlay image 0.jpg on timestamps 0 to 5 seconds of `2:v`. However, the filter lifetime is as long as the duration of the longer input - the color input, so indefinite. All enable does is decide when the compositing happens.

3) The concat filter switches to the next segment when the current segment ends. The first segment never ends, so when ffmpeg stops at `-t 00:00:10`, concat is still sending frames from the first segment - the first 5 seconds with the overlaid image 0 and then the base white stream.

4) If that's corrected by making the first segment of finite length, concat will stitch segments starting with timestamp 0 of the next segment, and your enable for the next segment is `between(t,5.01,10)`, so if your `-t` when up to 15s, you would see first 5 seconds with 0.jpg, then 5 seconds of white, and then 5 seconds of 1.jpg

Broadly, there are two ways to resolve this. Overlay each new image on the result of the last overlay, or overlay each image on a different stream, trim those results and then concat.

Overlay, in sequence:

```
ffmpeg
  -loop 1 -i "0.jpg"
  -loop 1 -i "1.jpg"
  -f lavfi
  -i color=c=white:s=1080x1080
  -filter_complex "

    [0:v]scale=1194:1490[out1];
    [1:v]scale=1176:1763[out2];

    [2:v][out1]overlay=-56:-119:enable='between(t,0,5)'[out101];
    [out101][out2]overlay=-47:-250:enable='between(t,5.01,10)'[main]

  "
  -map "[main]"
  -ac 2
  -vcodec libx264
  -preset veryfast
  -crf 27
  -pix_fmt yuv420p
  -vb 20M
  -t 00:00:10
  out.mp4
```

Concat:

```
ffmpeg
  -i "0.jpg"
  -i "1.jpg"
  -f lavfi
  -i color=c=white:s=1080x1080
  -filter_complex "

    [0:v]scale=1194:1490[out1];
    [1:v]scale=1176:1763[out2];

    [2:v][out1]overlay=-56:-119,trim=duration=5[out101];
    [2:v][out2]overlay=-47:-250,trim=duration=5[out102];

    [out101][out102]concat=n=2[main]

  "
  -map "[main]"
  -ac 2
  -vcodec libx264
  -preset veryfast
  -crf 27
  -pix_fmt yuv420p
  -vb 20M
  -t 00:00:10
  out.mp4
```